# Two fans on a single switch... run slow?

Tags: ceiling-fan, smart-switch

I recorded a video… in this video it shows 3 fans. These are Hunter Gallegos AC fans, and have no pull chains. The speeds are operated completely by Inovelli VZM35-SN wall switches. The switches are set at “low” (33%) speed.

https://i.imgur.com/nEoXfdf.mp4

The fan in the front is by itself on a switch. You’ll notice the speed. All single fans in my house that are tied to a switch, are running at this speed.

The two fans in the back are tied together, being controlled by a single switch. You’ll notice that the double fans are running slower than the single fan. In two places in my house, I have this two-fan on one-switch setup, and in both places, the fans run slower. To test, I disconnected one of the fans, and the other fan ran at normal speed. It’s only running slower when two fans are connected to the single switch.

Is this normal?

Comment: Are these fans wired in series instead of parallel?

Comment: Maximum Load (Watts): 2.5 Amps (No more than 2 fans on the switch)

Comment: @asinine there are two fans on the switch.

Comment: @asinine I saw the same specs. And then checked the fan specs - 44W, which is < 0.5A per fan. So in theory 2 of the same fan type should work.

Comment: @JimmyJames I have no idea...

Comment: @JimmyJames  Seems to be the answer.  If they are wired wrong the voltage will be reduce with both devices on.

Comment: @crip659 If they are in series, I would expect disconnecting one to disconnect both.  It may not be that simple.

Comment: @JimmyJames I just disconnected one of the fans, and the other fan still works... in fact, it sped up back to normal speed. So I don't believe this is the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  It was just my first thought.  Have you tried disconnecting each fan separately with the same outcome?

Comment: @JimmyJames yeah, made no difference which fan I disconnected. So they are definitely in parallel.

Comment: What happens when you set both switches to high?  Are the coupled fans still slower than the singleton?

Comment: On high, the double fans still run slower than the single fan.

Comment: I'm stumped and unless one of the electrical geniuses like manassehkatz come up with anything, I'd suggest you contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @JimmyJames  I'm no electrical genius. Just read and think a lot. But thanks for the compliment. But in any case, the very fact of a strict limit of 2 *and* the way speed controls are done (in general) makes me suspect that even with 2 it isn't necessarily going to work so well. It is conceptually the same as dimming lights but practically quite different.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you set both fans to max speed before connecting the controller? There is a note [here](https://help.inovelli.com/en/articles/8318193-blue-series-fan-switch-manual) which says: "Before installing your fan switch, please ensure the fan motor is set to high speed. If you notice that after you install your fan switch the speeds are not as fast as they were prior to installing your switch, it's likely that the motor was not on high (please adjust if you find this is the case)."

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Huh. I figured you were a pro of some flavor. Anyway, it's almost like the switch is controlling the available amperage, but I feel a little silly suggesting that.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Interesting but I don't see how that explains the fans running at full speed when the other is disconnected.

Comment: @JimmyJames I am an IT guy. I have done basic low-voltage wiring (modems, serial ports, DSL, ethernet, etc.) for 40+ years. I only work on 120V/240V in my own home, but I have learned a lot over the last several years both by doing things and through DIY SE.

Comment: @TomCarpenter setting the fan to "max speed" is only relevant if the fan itself has a speed control. This fan is an AC fan, and has no speed controls. The fan speed is controlled entirely by the load on the switch. There are no pull chains or canopy.